# Accessing function from running activity in another class (android)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm creating an android application and I am trying to access a method from a running fragment within a thread of another class, however, with my current implementation I am getting a null pointer error on the bolded line: FirstFragment.getInstance().onReceive(incomingMessage);

```
public void run(){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            // Read from the InputStream
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

                **FirstFragment.getInstance().onReceive(incomingMessage);**

                Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

There's a static instance variable initialized in the FirstFragment class and I'm using a getter function to access it in this class. Is there another way to access this method properly? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling the `run()` function from inside `FirstFragment`, just create an interface that acts as a listener, your code will look as follows :

```
    public interface OnReceiveListener {
    void onReceive(String incomingMessage);
} 


public void run(OnReceiveListener  listener){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            // Read from the InputStream
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);


                listener.onReceive(incomingMessage)    
                Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can call any method inside the fragment when you override the onReceive(someString) method and call any function you wish inside it